# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loadChildren')

Tags: angular

I'm moving an existing Angular 10 project into a new multi-project workspace without changing the source. After creating the workspace and moving the project to it I am getting an error during build:

```
ERROR in Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loadChildren')
```

There are no other errors. I have not changed any ts or compile options as far as I can tell. The route definitions that use loadChildren all look similar to this:

```
  { path: 'devices/:groupid',
    component: DevicesComponent,
    data: { title: 'menu-devices', redirectOnFail: 'login' },
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'group/:id',
        loadChildren: () => import('./group-overview/group-overview.module')
            .then(m => m.GroupOverviewModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'device/:id',
        loadChildren: () => import('./device-overview/device-overview.module')
            .then(m => m.DeviceOverviewModule)
      }
    ]
  },
```

The modules are fairly standard:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    SomeModules,
    EffectsModule.forFeature([GroupRulesTabEffectsService]),
    StoreModule.forFeature('groupRulesTab', GroupRulesTabReducer),
],
declarations: [
    SomeComponents
],
entryComponents: [
],
providers: [
    SomeServices
],
})
export class GroupOverviewModule {}
```

Neither Google nor SO have been helpful in discovering what the cause and meaning of this error are.

What does this error message mean in practical terms?

Comment: Error message in this context sounds strange. AFAIK it's thrown when trying to access a property of an undefined variable. My rudimentary knowledge of your project hints it might be some sort of syntax issue. Missing comma or something like that. Or there might be some `.loadChildren` or `['loadChildres']` where it's not supposed to be.

Comment: The code is unchanged, it built before, and doesn't have any elementary syntax issues. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: run npm i and then ng serve

Comment: if this is the only loadChildren in your code,, then it means route module is not properly installed in your new project.

Comment: furthest I can tell is it's a race of some sort during compilation when running `ng serve`. I can simply remove whitespace between brackets in my app-routing.module.ts file to kick it and it begins to work. Not sure if it's new since I last did `npm install` or if it's the introduction of a matcher function for one of my child paths (likely the latter).